# How get HTML without remove child (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

There are some problems with changing the js-object.
It has the html structure.
Example:

```
myObj.html ='<span class="first">la-la-la</span>
            <span class="second">la-la-la</span>';
```

And structure due to user actions is changing( add,delete elements ):

```
$(myObj.html).find('.second').remove()
```

Theoretically it has to help. But I work with just string (it is not real DOM element).
myObj.html don't save changing, and .remove() return deleted element.
And I want that myObj.html changed too:

```
myObj.html ='<span class="first">la-la-la</span>;
```

How to be in this situation? (RegExp is not better idea)

Comment: not sure of what you want, but assuming you just have a string with that structure and it has a line break like it seems to have, you could try something like: `myObj.html =myObj.html.split('\n')[0];`

Comment: No-no-no... Probably all this because of my bad Inglish :)
Chris solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `.html(myObj.html)` on a temporary element, you can do whatever you want, then read it back afterwards:

```js
var myObj = {};

myObj.html ='<span class="first">la-la-la</span><span class="second">la-la-la</span>';

$tmp = $("<div>").html(myObj.html);
$tmp.find(".second").remove();
myObj.html = $tmp.html(); 

console.log(myObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ouhhh!
It really works! Not really beautiful, but works!
Chris, you are genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try the following by using `createElement()` and delete the element afterwords:

```js
let myObj ='<span class="first">la-la-la</span><span class="second">la-la-la</span>';
let myObjHTMLDiv = document.createElement('div');
myObjHTMLDiv.innerHTML = myObj;
$(myObjHTMLDiv).find('.second').remove();
myObj = myObjHTMLDiv.innerHTML;
delete myObjHTMLDiv;
console.log(myObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```